# Sorting file contents idiomatically with spring-batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a CSV file with a number of fields. What is an **idiomatic** way to read the file, sort the file using a subset of fields, and then write another CSV as output.

Should I even attempt to do this in spring-batch? I understand that *nix-based OSes have the `sort` utility to do this, but I'd like to contain all my work within spring batch if possible.

The [Batch Processing Strategies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html#batchProcessingStrategy) section of the documentation seems to suggest that might be standard utility steps to accomplish this:

> In addition to the main building blocks, each application may use one or more of standard utility steps, such as:
>
> Sort: A program that reads an input file and produces an output file where records have been re-sequenced according to a sort key field in the records. Sorts are usually performed by standard system utilities.

But I am not able to locate this. Any pointers most welcome!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really should do it inside Spring Batch I would suggest you do it with OS based commands.

But your **point is correct**, adding intermediary Steps to your Jobs to Sort/Filter or even clean DATA is a mainstream pattern used in Batch Processing or ETL Jobs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a `SystemCommandTasklet` that is meant to run OS commands. This can be used to do things like sorting, finding unique items, etc.